# Python: Which numpy float type is better for Blender?

Tags: python, numpy

I've been working on addons for blender (modeling, sculpting). I use millions of vertex positions/normals through Numpy. Which Float Type is better for Blender? float16, float32, float64? What type of floats are in Blender for vertices/UVs?

Right now I'm using float64 like this:

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

act_obj = bpy.context.active_object
np_test = np.zeros(len(act_obj.data.vertices) * 3, dtype=np.float64)
act_obj.data.vertices.data.foreach_get('co', np_test )
```